# Django not reconnecting when PostgreSQL dies, custom backend needed?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, backend, custom-backend

I have been doing some testing and have been able to confirm that using `Django` with `PostgreSQL` and `PGBouncer` that it does not automatically reconnect on losing it's connection. To be honest, I am not sure if this is a bug or if this is by design. If it is a bug I will happily report it, if not I would like some explanation of why and how to get around it other than another custom back end.

I did these tests fairly easily by doing the following on `Django 1.8.4` and on `Django 1.8.6`:

```
>>>Model.objects.all().count()
24
# Restart postgres with `sudo service postgres restart`
>>>Model.objects.all().count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 318, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 466, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 447, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

It does not matter how long I wait after restarting `PostgreSQL` to run the query I still get the same results. I see that in `Django` there is code to run a `Select 1` to check for a connection but that doesn't seem to be working. Back in `Django 1.5.x` we had written a custom PostgreSQL back end to do this same thing but removed it since it seemed `Django` had it built in when we upgraded.  Is this a bug?

**Edit 11/6/2015:** In Django, the PostgreSQL backend implements the `is_usable` function that does a `SELECT 1` on the database. However, I am not able to find any usages of `is_usable` other than in `close_if_unusable_or_obsolete` but I couldn't find any usages of that anywhere. I would think it would be used within some database wrapper that catches exceptions and retries/reconnects based on `is_usable`.

The code mentioned above is found at `django/db/backends/postgresql_psychopg2/base.py` in Django 1.8.

**Edit 2 11/6/2015:** Ok, I wrote my own custom wrapper for the database and just overrode `ensure_connection` method to try and reconnect to the database when the connection is lost. However, on the first attempt to hit the database for a session I get this other gnarly traceback. But if I immediately query again it works. If I wrap what I am doing in a `try/except: pass` block it all **seems** to be working fine but cannot really tell if it will cause problems later on. Here is the traceback and code.

```
>>> c = Model.objects.all().count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 318, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 466, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 447, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 838, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 164, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/custom/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 73, in ensure_connection
    self._reconnect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/custom/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 63, in _reconnect
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 120, in connect
    self.set_autocommit(self.settings_dict['AUTOCOMMIT'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 295, in set_autocommit
    self._set_autocommit(autocommit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 218, in _set_autocommit
    self.connection.autocommit = autocommit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 218, in _set_autocommit
    self.connection.autocommit = autocommit
ProgrammingError: autocommit cannot be used inside a transaction
```

Now for the code:

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base import DatabaseError, \
    IntegrityError, DatabaseWrapper as PostgresWrapper

class DatabaseWrapper(PostgresWrapper):
    def _reconnect(self):
        try:
            self.connect()
        except (DatabaseError, OperationalError):
            pass

    def ensure_connection(self):
        """
        Guarantees that a connection to the database is established.
        """
        if self.connection is None:
            with self.wrap_database_errors:
                self._reconnect()
        else:
            try:
                self.connection.cursor().execute('SELECT 1')
            except (DatabaseError, OperationalError):
                self._reconnect()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out...finally. Not entirely sure what was wrong with my first approach but this one seems to be working a ton better.

```
class DatabaseWrapper(PostgresWrapper):
    def _cursor(self):
        if self.connection is not None:
            if not self.is_usable():
                self.connection.close()
                self.connection = None
        return super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
```

**Edit:** Ended up open sourcing this. I am not sure if it is 100% needed, but it is working correctly after restarting the Postgres service on the server. You can find it on pypi as `django-postgreconnect`, and on GitHub: https://github.com/EccoTheFlintstone/django-postgreconnect.

Comment: How often did you run into this issue? What was causing your connection to break? I am worried of a similar problem with my elasticsearch cluster using `django_elasticsearch_dsl` ...